# NodeJs heap-js module: Heap is not a constructor

Tags: javascript, node.js, data-structures, module, heap

I am trying to initialize a minimum heap/priority queue in my server.js using the head-js module (https://github.com/ignlg/heap-js). When I run my code, I receive the following error:

> ```
> var minHeap = new Heap(customComparator);
> ```
>
> TypeError: Heap is not a constructor

However, according to the documentation, I am initializing the heap correctly, putting in a custom constructor as the parameter. Below is my code:

```
var Heap = require("heap-js");
// Build a minimum heap of size k containing the k cities with the most active users
var customComparator = (city1, city2) => citySizes[city1] - citySizes[city2];
var minHeap = new Heap(customComparator);
```

Comment: `var {Heap} = require("heap-js");` forgot destructuring

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a difference between using `heap-js` library in **CommonJS** and **ES6 modules**.

When `require`ing (i.e. CommonJS) you need to destruct out the `Heap` class from the object returned, like so:

```
const { Heap } = require('heap-js') // correct
const Heap = require('heap-js') // incorrect
```

Whereas, you have to do the opposite in ES6, as shown below:

```
import Heap from 'heap-js' // correct
import { Heap } from 'heap-js' // incorrect
```